# проблема с файловым вводом-выводом на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловый-ввод-вывод

Есть файл, в котором вперемешку русский, украинский и английский языки, больше *270,000,000* знаков, нужно оставить только русский текст. Написал такую программу на Python:

```
import time

from tqdm import tqdm

alphabet = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 0123456789,.!?'
fin = open("C:/Users/...../file.txt")
fout = open("C:/Users/...../file_new.doc", "w")
print("\033[31m {}".format('Придется немного подождать!'))
progres = [i for i in range(100)]

for i in tqdm(progres):
    for letter in fin.read():
        if letter in alphabet:
            fout.write(letter)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Все работает нормально, но вот с кириллицей проблема, удаляет только знаки украинского языка которые не в ходят в алфавит русского, а остальное все оставляет, подскажите куда копать пожалуйста, как выйти из ситуации. Пытался проверять каждую строку на наличие например "і, ї, є" и при первом вхождении удалять всю строку, но не могу додуматься как реализовать это в такой интерпретации.

Comment: если с регулярными выражениями знакомы, попробуйте использовать их

Comment: Читайте файл построчно и сохраняйте только те строки, в которых нет латинских и украинских букв.

Comment: Имеет ли файл структуру? Например: абзац английского, потому русского, потом украинского? Или просто набор предложений на разных языках в произвольном порядке? Если задача учебная и секретной информации не содержит, можете выложить фрагмент файла (лучше побольше - размером около 1 мб) куда-нибудь и дать здесь ссылку - картина станет яснее, возможно кто-нибудь даст решение.

Comment: Думаю можно поэкспериментировать с [различными языковыми анализаторами/определителями](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106810/2913477)

Comment: Структура есть, к сожалению выложить не могу так как писал программу для друга переводчика, для его рабочих нужд. Пока обошлись удалением латиницы, с кириллицей есть проблемы так как в файле встречаются короткие строки на украинском, в которых нет характерных знаков, например: "....Коли ми будемо дивитись на сонце....". Даже не представляю как это можно реализовать, я нахожусь на стадии обучения программированию, поэтому слабо понимаю такие нюансы, наверное в таких случаях для распознавания языка без ИИ не обойтись. А за подсказку с анализатором, спасибо, попробую повозиться.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал list comprehesnsions?

```
[x for x in text if x in symbols]
```

где symbols - это кирилица и цифры, text - твой текст

```
`alphabet = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 0123456789,.!?'
text = "Magic is here  АБВгтвыа 546123 !! ы ӘІҢҒ"
print(''.join([x for x in text if x in alphabet]))`
```

например вот это работает для меня